# jQuery selectors: concisely select all form elements within multiple containers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given a form with multiple `div`s containing form elements (`input`, `textarea`, `select`), what would be the most concise way of selecting the `input`, `textarea` and `select` within given `div` IDs?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2rvxt5v7/4

**I know this is invalid jQuery syntax**, but maybe this will demonstrate what I'm trying to do (select the elements within area1 and area3 without selecting those in area2):

```
$('#area1[input,select,textarea], #area3[input,select,textarea]').css('background-color','yellow')
```

I note there are libraries out there that add a regular expression method of providing selectors, but I would like a native jQuery way of doing this. Preferably without using `.filter()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector.

```
$('#area1 :input, #area3 :input').css('background','yellow')
```

> Selects all `input`, `textarea`, `select` and `button` elements.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5vtxr8x4/)

Note that this will select `<button>` elements also, probably not what you want.

---

The button elements can be excluded using [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) and [`:button`](https://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) selector.

```
$('#area1 :input, #area3 :input').not(':button').css(...
```

Comment: Ah good find - didn't realise there was :input.  I can easily use a :not to exclude buttons.  This could work, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for updating the fiddle - your solution is ideal

Comment: @psynnott Welcome. Glad that helped. :)

Comment: I'll update the question title as what I was needing was only form fields.